# XSLT - Displays all node data on each line (should split up on the different nodes/lines)

Tags: xslt

I have a problem. Whatever I do, I can't get the NetMass to be split up on each node. In the output all NetMass is displayed after each other on the same node. I guess it's just something plain and simple I am just overlooking, but thankfull for all input. Still trying to teach this :) Thanks for all input!

Parts of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <Invoice>
    <TotalExVat>18102.63</TotalExVat>
    <TotNetMass>5248.00</TotNetMass>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>1</LineNo>
      <NetMass></NetMass>
      <AmountExVat>4358.15</AmountExVat>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>2</LineNo>
      <NetMass></NetMass>
      <AmountExVat>4358.15</AmountExVat>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>3</LineNo>
      <NetMass></NetMass>
      <AmountExVat>8461.71</AmountExVat>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>4</LineNo>
      <NetMass></NetMass>
      <AmountExVat>462.31</AmountExVat>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>5</LineNo>
      <NetMass></NetMass>
      <AmountExVat>462.31</AmountExVat>
    </InvoiceLine>
  </Invoice>
</Job>
```

Parts of the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="Job">
        <xsl:element name="Invoice">
          <xsl:element name="TotalExVat">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Job/Invoice/TotalExVat"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="TotNetMass">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Job/Invoice/TotNetMass"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:for-each select="Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine">
            <xsl:element name="InvoiceLine">
              <xsl:element name="NetMass">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="NetMass"/>
              </xsl:element>
              <xsl:element name="AmountExVat">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="AmountExVat"/>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NetMass">
      <xsl:variable name="NetFactor" select="number(translate(//Job/Invoice/TotNetMass,',','.')) div number(translate(//Job/Invoice/TotalExVat,',','.'))"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine">      
        <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(AmountExVat,',','.')) * $NetFactor"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Job>
   <Invoice>
      <TotalExVat>18102.63</TotalExVat>
      <TotNetMass>5248.00</TotNetMass>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>1</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.4391356394071263.4391356394072453.0719613669394134.02488367712314134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>4358.15</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>2</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.4391356394071263.4391356394072453.0719613669394134.02488367712314134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>4358.15</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>3</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.4391356394071263.4391356394072453.0719613669394134.02488367712314134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
         <AmountExVat>8461.71</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>4</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.4391356394071263.4391356394072453.0719613669394134.02488367712314134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>462.31</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>5</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.4391356394071263.4391356394072453.0719613669394134.02488367712314134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>462.31</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
   </Invoice>
</Job>
```

Want it like this:

```
<Job>
   <Invoice>
      <TotalExVat>18102.63</TotalExVat>
      <TotNetMass>5248.00</TotNetMass>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>1</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.439135639407</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>4358.15</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>2</LineNo>
         <NetMass>1263.439135639407</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>4358.15</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>3</LineNo>
         <NetMass>2453.0719613669394</NetMass>
         <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
         <AmountExVat>8461.71</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>4</LineNo>
         <NetMass>134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>462.31</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <LineNo>5</LineNo>
         <NetMass>134.02488367712314</NetMass>
         <AmountExVat>462.31</AmountExVat>
      </InvoiceLine>
   </Invoice>
</Job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the main task is the computation for the missing content of the `NetMass` so I would write a template for that and handle the copying of the rest minus the namespaces with single, separate template:

```
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NetMass">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Invoice!(TotNetMass div TotalExVat) * ../AmountExVat"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

That uses XSLT 3 (as supported on a wide range of platforms (Java, .NET, C/C++) through Saxon 9.8), full example is online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NetMass">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Invoice!(TotNetMass div TotalExVat) * ../AmountExVat"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 1 I would transcribe that as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NetMass">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Invoice/TotNetMass div ancestor::Invoice/TotalExVat * ../AmountExVat"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTy/1